# How to replicate design documents only?

Tags: couchdb

So I want to replicate some changes I made to my design files from dev to production (a.k.a. I want to deploy something).

I'm somehow confused since my research did not lead to any concrete results. Although this seams IMHO like a pretty obvious use case.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can specify the document IDs to replicate, without having to write a filter. Post the replication document (or command) like so:

```
{ "source": "my_db"
, "target": "http://target:5984/target_db"
, "doc_ids": [ "_design/my_ddoc" ]
}
```

Comment: Also the way faster solution. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you are using admin user for the replication to succeed 
under target pass user/pass in the url "target":"http://admin:password@ip/db" , 
only admins can create design documents

Answer (score 9):

You can use 'Filtered Replication' (See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication for details)

Basically, you'll supply a function that returns true for design documents like;

```
function(doc, req) {
  return "_design/" === doc._id.substr(0, 8)
}
```

and then add "filter":"ddocname/filtername" to your _replicate request body.

Comment: In this case you probably want to just replicate the named ID as shown by JasonSmith and not perform a more general replication.

Comment: Robert's solution most directly answers the question. In my solution, you must know the document IDs. In his, CouchDB figures that out for you. I think in practice, people do indeed know their design document ids however.

Comment: I have found filters to be very slow. Using the name of the design doc is better for most cases.

Comment: This fits a database-per-user pattern pretty well. Especially if you're already doing a filtered replication to populate the new users database.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my design documents stored as .js files on disk. Then I use [couchdb-update-views](https://github.com/nisaacson/couchdb-update-views) to update the design documents on a server

```
npm install -g couchdb-update-views
couchdb-update-views --config /path/to/config.json --docsDir /path/to/design/docs/directory/
```